# how to check whether an image have alt attribute or not in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass, hasattr

i want to add one Class to an image if it have alt attribute and one class to an image which doesnot have an alt attribute.

i tried this but its not working

```
if ($(img).hasAttr('alt'))
{
    this.addClass("haveAlt");   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use attribute selector:

```
$('img[alt]').addClass('haveAlt');
```

For the ones which don't have `alt` attribute, use `:not` selector:

```
$('img:not([alt])').addClass('noAlt');
```

As as side note to hande both cases in one function call, you can use:

```
$('img').addClass(function(){
    return this.alt ? "haveAlt": "noAlt";
});
```

Comment: thank u.. its working but i also want to add class to an image which doesnot have an alt attribute

Comment: @simr Updated answer, use `:not()` selector

Comment: thank u so much... (y) everything working fine now :)